# “SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input”

Tags: javascript, react-native

Trying to fetch data from API using async/await, but facing the above error after session expiration, how to handle that error and show user session expired or any other helpful error?

```
export const walletAddCardRequest = async (dispatch, token, payload, url) => {
  try {

      persist.store.dispatch(setLoader(true));
      const headers = {Authorization: token}
      const response = await api(url, "POST", payload, headers);
      console.log("wallet add card ", response);
      persist.store.dispatch(setLoader(false));
      if (response.status === 200) {
          const user = await response.json();
          if (user) {
              persist.store.dispatch(setLoader(false));
              Alert.alert(
                  "",
                  "Your card added successfully."
              );
                navigateTo("wallet");
          } else {
              throw new Error("Error. Please try again");
          }
      } else {}
  } catch (e) {
      persist.store.dispatch(setLoader(false));
      Alert.alert(e.message);
      console.log("console:",e);
      dispatch({
          type: AUTH_ERROR
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: You should see more on the error in the console

Comment: Unexpected end of JSON input error means that something is trying to parse JSON data that isn't complete, or isn't a JSON structure at all. I suspect it is `const user = await response.json();` that is throwing the error, and I would print out and inspect the data inside `response` to make sure that it is indeed proper JSON.

Comment: Are you using redux library? You have a try...catch in your code, once an error was caught an error action will be dispatched, everything looks good. If you need to show a UI to user you only need to add a reducer to handle the AUTH_ERROR action, save the error message to store and connect to a ui component.